# "white-space: pre-line" causes weird stretching on non-block elements

Tags: css, webkit, whitespace, blink

When using `white-space: pre-line` on non-`block` elements, Chrome, Opera and Safari (I suspect WebKit- and WebKit-derivative-based browsers) seem to stretch the element to seemingly fit the whitespace, which I believe they are supposed to collapse.

```css
div
{
    white-space: pre-line;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #333;
}
```

```html
<!-- deep inside the document, on the 20th indentation level -->
                                        <div>single line</div>
                                        <div>multi
                                             line</div>
                                        <div>multi
                                             line
                                        </div>
                                                                                                                                <div>crazy
                                                                                                                                     indentation
                                                                                                                                </div>
```

In Chrome, Opera and Safari the above code produces:

[image: screenshot]

While in Firefox, it turns up (somewhat) as I would expect it to:

[image: screenshot]

Interestingly, this seems to  determined only by the length of the last line of the element:

```css
div
{
    white-space: pre-line;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #333;
}
```

```html
<!-- deep inside the document, on the 20th indentation level -->
                                        <div>multi
                                             line
</div> <!-- last line has 0 characters -->
```

According to my understanding of [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#propdef-white-space), `white-space: pre-line` is supposed to collapse multiple consecutive spaces (and tabs) into at most a single character.
This seems to be happening to some extent, as there is no whitespace to be selected with the mouse in the boxes in the first example.
However, the box model seems to treat the last line of its content as if `white-space: pre` had been applied.

- Is this a bug in the WebKit engine, or is there some obscure reason for which this is allowed, or even supposed to be happening?
- There are at least two HTML workarounds (use `<br>` or remove indentation), but I'd rather leave my markup readable. So is there a CSS-only way to "fix" the box width?

Comment: Isn't Chrome using their Blink engine in the most recent updates? I would probably do a bug report and see what the guys and gals at Google have to say about spec compliance on that issue.

Comment: @Korgrue I wasn't aware that they are doing their own think now, but that seems to be the case indeed. However, Blink is apparently a fork of WebKit's WebCore module, which probably explains the browsers behaving all the same.But I'll go bug the people on the Chromium issue tracker then.

Comment: And [it seems to be a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=490360) indeed.